# What is the difference between InnerJoin WITH and inner join ON?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When reading Doctrine 2 Documentation [at this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) I can see they have 2 ways to specify a condition for the inner join :

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, 'g.manager_level = 100');
// Example - $qb->expr()->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->eq('g.manager_level', '100'));
public function innerJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null); // Returns Expr\Join instance
```

and

```
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::ON, $qb->expr()->and($qb->expr()->eq('u.group_id', 'g.id'), 'g.name = ?1'))
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'ON', 'u.group_id = g.id AND g.name = ?1')
public function innerJoin($join, $alias = null, $conditionType = null, $condition = null);
```

I don't understand the difference as innerjoin returns content ONLY when it finds a match and I can't find any documentation about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they're synonymous. Based on the Doctrine EBNF expression (found at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#from-join-and-index-by), it appears that Doctrine prefers `WITH`. However, MySQL (and probably other SQL databases) use `ON`, so my guess is that the author(s) of Doctrine included that expression to avoid confusing their users.

The developers of Doctrine have written their own variant of SQL - this is because Doctrine is an Object-Relation Manager (ORM), not a straight-forward query builder. Their variant of SQL is intended to work with their objects. So, for example, if you're building `user` and `group` models and want to express the relation between them, you can do so in Doctrine's query language and it will take care of the `JOIN` conditions automagically.

Comment: Thanks, so, basically, ON and WITH do the exact same thing here?

Comment: I believe so... that's what I got from reading the documentation. I've never used Doctrine, though.

Answer (score -1):

I liked this explanation:

> INNER JOIN is the default if you don't specify the type when you use the word JOIN.
>
> You can also use LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN, in which case the word OUTER is optional, or >you can specify CROSS JOIN.

Comment: That's not the question here, I know the difference between Righ left inner and outer join. here it is about ON and WITH as condition for the inner join